# Why is the option "Include in VSIX option" missing

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I have a "Visual Studio Extension" project which I created using Visual Studio 2019.

If I add files to the project - for example a help file - I expect to see the option **"Include in VSIX"** in the properties window for that file. The option is missing in this project.

I have just created a new "Visual Studio Extension" project and added an additional file. In this case, the option "Include in VSIX" is present, so it looks like a problem in my specific project.

I guess there is something different in the project file. Does anybody know what it might be?

By the way, the project type GUID {82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60} which indicates an extensibility project is present.

In addition, if I patch the option `<IncludeInVSIX>true</IncludeInVSIX>` into the project file for the required file, the file does get included in the VSIX installation.

Comment: What's the file extension of your help file? And you can easily check if this issue comes from project file by comparing these two project files. Or delete the .vs file and restart vs to check if this issue helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project file (.csproj) there is a list of project type guids. The list was:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>
  {60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};
  {82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60};
  {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

(actually all on one line).

These GUIDS mean (in the above order)

- WPF project
- Extensibility project
- C# project

I have changed the sequence to

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>
  {82b43b9b-a64c-4715-b499-d71e9ca2bd60};
  {60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};
  {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

(again, it is actually on one line)

That is, I have moved the GUID which indicates an extensibility project to the start of the list. Now the "Include in VSIX" appears.

Comment: Useful info obviously, thanks for your sharing, why not mark it as answer? Just a reminder:)

Comment: I thought you had to wait a day to mark it as an answer, if you answer your own question. Seems I was wrong, because it worked now after 12 hours.